# Radio input form with custom buttons

Tags: html, css, reactjs, input, frontend

I would like to achieve the behavior of a **radio** input but with custom buttons (instead of those round checkboxes).

At the end the behavior should be the same (just 1 must be selected) and when clicked it should preserve its state (at the image the *option1* was selected).

I am using React but I with any other suggestion it may help

[image: Desired radio input]

Comment: Could you provide some of your code, or an online demo?

Comment: https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/MWaKJLq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a `radio` is not the best for what you need. You should create a component with a `selectedTab` prop that changes the style a `div` (for example) to give it the red colour and check which tab is selected using that prop.

For example

```
// ...

<div className={selectedTab === 1 ? "red" : "gray"} onClick={() => setSelectedTab(1)} />
<div className={selectedTab === 2 ? "red" : "gray"} onClick={() => setSelectedTab(2)} />

// ...
```